# Closing popup window

Tags: javascript, window

I found a code that takes care of opening popup window I need:

```
 function winOpen(theURL, Name, popW, popH, scroll) { // V 1.0
 var winleft = (screen.width - popW) / 2;
 var winUp = (screen.height - popH) / 2;
 winProp =
'width='+popW+',height='+popH+',left='+winleft+',t op='+winUp+',scrollbars='+scroll+','
  Win = window.open(theURL, Name, winProp)
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4){
      Win.window.focus();
   }
```

Is it possible to include here functions, that are commited when the window is closed, or does it require a separate function call somewhere? I'm calling window open on a html link.

Answer (score 0):

The page you are showing inside the popup could have an event handler attached to the `body`'s `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` (I think that is IE only). That will fire if the document unloads *(who would have guessed that?)*. If you don't ave links inside the document that will unload it, you can take this event as an indicator that your window has been closed.

Second possibility: add a watchdog.

```
var watcherID = setInterval(function()
{
  if (Win.closed)
  {
    clearTimeout(watcherID);
    // Do what you have to do.
  }
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indent your code a little to make it more readable. Also, you can use `win.closed` to see it's closed `onunload`, but make sure to wait a little before checking: http://jsfiddle.net/9PYWj/.

```
function winOpen(theURL, Name, popW, popH, scroll) { // V 1.0
    var winleft = (screen.width - popW) / 2,
        winUp   = (screen.height - popH) / 2,

        winProp = 'width=' + popW 
                   + ',height=' + popH 
                   + ',left=' + winleft 
                   + ',top=' + winUp 
                   + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',',

        win     = window.open(theURL, Name, winProp);

    win.onunload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(win.closed) {
                alert(123);
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    win.focus();
}
```